# Data binding in directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a collection of buttons that sort a list of items when clicked:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <sort-buttons target="filters.sort">
        <sort-button></sort-button>
        <sort-button></sort-button>
        <sort-button></sort-button>
    </sort-buttons>
</div>
```

I want the parent directive to save the results of the buttons to the `$scope.filters.sort` property on the `MainCtrl` controller via the `target` attribute, but how can I actually **save** to where the `target` attribute points to?

Here's what I have:

```
app.directive('sortButtons', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {                
            // this.foo() should save to target
            this.foo = function(){
                console.log('click');
            };
        }
    }
}]).directive('sortButton', ['Config', function(Config) {
    var basePath = Config.get().paths.base;

    return {
        restrict:    'AE',
        replace:     true,
        require:     '^sortButtons',
        scope:       {
            label:   '@',
            orderBy: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: basePath + 'js/fantasy/templates/sort-button.htm',
        link:        function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.on('click', function(){
                ctrl.foo();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Where is the sorting happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$eval` on `attr.target` like

```
var data = $scope.$eval($attrs.target)
```

Or if your data is dynamic you can $watch the attr

```
var data = [];
$scope.$watch($attrs.target, function(newValue, oldValue){
   data = newValue;
})
```

Also correct your controller injection like below, else if you will get error if you minified your source code.

```
 controller: ['$scope','$element','$attrs', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var data = $scope.$eval($attrs.target)

        this.foo = function(){
            console.log('click');
        };
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I went with was removing the `target` attribute altogether, and instead broadcasting on the `$rootScope`.

Directive:

```
this.foo = function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('sortButtons', {
        predicate: 'foo',
        reverse:    false
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('sortButtons', function(event, data){
    $scope.filters.sort = data;
});
```